# Use RD Gateway to direct users to certain term server?

Tags: terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

Is it possible to configure RD Gateway to, depending on a users group, point them to one term server or another? Just trying to make it work on the domain right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RD gateway is designed to allow you to go to an internal machine from an outside network (ie..Internet for example).  For example, connect to your desktop at the office from home wihtout exposing your desktop to the internet.

If you wanted to do this, you would simply specify which server you wanted them to connect to in the RDP client as well as specifiying the gateway.  Maybe point them to a CNAME that you can change in DNS so you can move them around if you want to.  something like  rdp1.domain.com CNAME to TS1.domain.com.  This way if you ever want to move them around later, you could.  If you don't have a ton of users, you could add a CNAME entry for each user and let DNS move them around for you when they login.  Keep in mind, you will probably have some certificate issues to overcome if the machine names don't match.  Not sure if RDP supports using subject alternate names in certs.

There is probably a much better way to do this as the above solution would be complicated to admin. A clustering solution might be easier, but probably not cheaper.

I can clarify more if needed, just ask away.

Comment: We currently have our 2003 terminal servers doing basic load balancing, they are not enterprise edition so the problem we run into is they can have 1 session but if they go to make another one theres still a chance they get on a different server. So for some of our users I need to make them user one server or the other. From what I initially saw of RD Gateway I thought it could do this but I was mistaken. Still looking for other possibilities.

Comment: RD Gateway will let you specify the internal machine you want to connect to and it will always connect to that.  But if you are trying to give yourself a way to bounce those users to the second server if the first fails, then you'd need a more complicated solution.  Some firewalls use a MOD of the IP to figure out which load balanced server to send the user to.  (Sonicwall does it this way).  So the user always connects to the same machine in the load balanced pool unless their IP changes or the server they were using goes offline.